# How to change Foreground of TextBlock in a style of a control through Datatemplate?

Tags: wpf

I have a style for control `InputField`, code xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type c:InputField}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:InputField}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Row="0" 
                           Foreground="{DynamicResource InputFieldLabelForegroundBrush}" Name="Label" 
                           />
                    <Border Grid.Row="1"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
Foreground="{DynamicResource InputFieldLabelForegroundBrush}" specification foreground of TextBlock.
```

I use this control InputField in a DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type g:ItemTextBox}">        
    <c:InputField Label="{Binding Caption}" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

It work fine with TextBlock has Foreground is InputFieldLabelForegroundBrush. I use `ItemTextBox` a lot of places. One of them is:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type v:DetailSettings}">
    <Border Width="290" Background="{DynamicResource DetailSettingsBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

`Properties` is `ItemTextBox`. My problem now is: "How to change `Foreground` of `TextBlock` in `InputField` only for this DataTemplate, that mean I must not change the `Foreground` color of `TextBlock` for all windows, but only for this `DataTemplate`?"
Thanks for help me !!!

Comment: Perhaps instead of setting the `Foreground` directly on the `TextBlock`, try setting it on the overall control itself. I think `Foreground` trickles down to child elements. If not, you can bind it to the `Textblock` using a template binding. Then you can modify the property on the control itself in the data template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Style`, use the `Setter` element to declare the foreground which by default, is your `InputFieldLabelForegroundBrush`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:InputField}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource InputFieldLabelForegroundBrush}"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

In the `Template` for your `Style`, you can then reference this by using a `TemplateBinding`.

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ... />
```

Now all you need to do in your `DataTemplate`, is explicitly set the `Foreground` on the `TextBlock`, and the `TemplateBinding` will do the rest.

```
<c:InputField Label="{Binding Caption}" Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="Red"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But so it will be change the Foreground color is RED of TextBlock for all windows, because there are many places use "g:ItemTextBox". I only want change foreground in DataTemplate of "v:DetailSettings".

Comment: Create a new `DataTemplate` (to be used by your v:DetailSettings), and give it an x:Key. In your `ItemsControl`, simply set the `ItemTemplate` to `{StaticResource whateverYouCalledIt}`. This will force the ItemsControl to use a different `DataTemplate`.